# How to do a not exists with a join in rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to do a semi complicated query in rails and I'm trying to figure out a way to do it in rails without running raw sql. How it works is I have a list of classes and it joins with table called days and each class has multiple days which is runs on.

I want to have a query where I give a list of days say monday tuesday and thursday and it will give me back a list of classes where all the days it runs on is in the list given.

I have the raw sql I can use but I can't figure out how to get this into a rails command.

```
select * from webtms_classes c 
where c.class_id = 'CHEM101'
and not exists (
  select cd.day from webtms_days cd
  where cd.webtms_class_id = c.id
  and cd.day not in ('Monday','Tuesday','Thursday')
)
```

Heres what the models are:

```
class WebtmsClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :webtms_days, dependent: :destroy
end

class WebtmsDay < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :webtms_class
end
```

Any advice?

Comment: Can you put your code in model to show how your association designed?

Comment: Consider filtering the classes in Ruby after fetching all of them. I don't see a nice solution that does not involve writing SQL or Arel.

Comment: @Raffael wouldn't it be better to write raw sql than load everything in to memory and manually filter. i feel like that would take wayy longer.

Comment: If you want to use plain SQL, you may do so. Just pass it into the `where` method as a string. Or use the `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all` method to avoid creating `ActiveRecord` objects at all. Performance considerations are only really relevant if you have several thousand classes in your db, though. For small datasets you should be fine with a Ruby approach, too.

Comment: i tried passing it into a where but the from webtms_days causes it to error out. I do need them to be active record objects so right now im doing WebtmsClass.find_by_sql() which seems to work for now

Answer (score 3):

You can use 'not exist' in Arel

```
days = WebtmsDay.arel_table
other_days = days[:day].not_in(['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Thursday'])

WebtmsClass.where(WebtmsDay.where(other_days).exists.not)
```